# calculate the angle between 0 and 90 with adding 15

Tags: c

I write this code to get sin of angles between 0 and 90

example:

```
1: sin(0) =
2: sin(15)=  
....
7: sin(90)=...
```

So I have written this code but he show me only one result
where is my problem ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    float x;

    for (i=0;i>90;i=i+15);
    {
        x = sin(i);
        printf("sin(%d)= %f\n", i, x);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should also read https://linux.die.net/man/3/sin , the argument is in radians, so `sin(90)` will not be `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of your faulty loop condition. You need to correct your for-loop from

```
for(i=0; i>90; i=i+15)
```

to

```
for (i=0; i<=90; i=i+15)
```

Also remove the `;` after the for-loop.

Comment: You should include @mch 's warning that the angle is not given in degree to your answer.